# Google Colab: cell has not been executed in this session?

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I am running a long hyperparameter tuning using TensorFlow on google colab (GPU runtime), which is expected to take a few hours.

However, after over half an hour of training, the "Run cell" button turns from grey to red, with the message reading "Run cell\ cell has not been executed in this session\ executed at unknown time" and the values stop from printing in the output cell. The kernel is probably still running since I can't execute any other cell (the run cell button keeps rotating).

- Why is this problem happening?
- Is there a way to prevent this from happening?
- If not, is there a way to measure the progress of the hyperparameter tuning given that the notebook stops from printing any outputs?

Thanks a lot.